# Strange prompt color issue with Solarized and OSX 10.11 Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, zsh, solarized

I am trying out some Terminal.app customization and have switched from the stock bash to zsh with oh-my-zsh. I have installed patched Powerline fonts and the a port of Solarized theme for the 256-color OSX Terminal (like everyone else) from [here](https://github.com/jcberthon/solarized/commit/b8f7484fed98de37736b7c025cbcea7647204fe6).

This is nitpicking, but the last triangle in the prompt shows up in a slightly altered color. [Here's a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iqDJ.jpg)

Notice the brighter triangle at the end of the prompt.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Notice that the blue triangle after `\NUCLEUS\nucleus` and before `Master` matches the other blue correctly.  Are you looking in the source code?  There may be some conditional statement that adjusts the saturation or hue or whatever if it's the last in the line, or something along those lines.  If you can narrow in on how these colors are handled in the source and share what you find, perhaps we can help you figure it out.  Have you asked the developers on GitHub?

Comment: @benJephunneh The "agnoster" theme's source is located [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme). It sounds like your probably right in that the problem is in the prompt customization. However, given that I'm new at this customization, the source is complete gibberish to me.

Comment: They mention this in the code's comments:
`# In order for this theme to render correctly, you will need a [Powerline-patched font](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts). Make sure you have a recent version: the code points that Powerline uses changed in 2012, and older versions will display incorrectly, in confusing ways.`
Also look here: `https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4352`

Comment: @benJephunneh Thank you! Looks like I'm forced to get iTerm2 after all...

Comment: This issue might be the culprit: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29487/is-it-possible-to-disable-terminals-automatic-tweaking-of-colors-in-lion

Comment: @egmont Thanks, though I've tried that. It appears to be as benJephunneh said that Terminal.app has "minimum contrast enforcement" that can't be tweaked.